# Cancelled Partition Deleting Operation on USB Drive, and it Stopped Showing Up

Tags: usb, partitioning

I was deleting my entire USB partition using AOMEI Partition Assistant, and midway through the operation I stopped the operation and closed the application.

Now my USB drive is not showing in either the software or Explorer.

How can I go about this?

Comment: First think unplug and plug back in the device. After that, check if you see it in Windows' ***Disk Management***.

Comment: It still didn't show up on disk management, but the lights on the usb drive are on to indicate its still working

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the full Disk Management window?